# Backup of Exchangeserver on VMWare server

Tags: backup, exchange, exchange-2010, vmware-esx

I have an Exchange Server 2010 running in a virtual machine on our VMWare Esx Server, and we do backups of the virtual machines regulary.

I heard somewhere that the Exchange Server should be stopped during the backup, because else I would risk a data loss. Is this true? Wouldn't this also imply that Exchange Server is not tolerant to a server power loss?

EDIT: I use VMWare ESX 3.5, and therefore do not have the vStorage API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange is based on [a variation of the Jet database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine), and does not need to be stopped in order to be backed up (in fact, it *shouldn't* be stopped because some important tasks are carried out as part of an "online" backup).

Exchange server backups should be carried out with an "Exchange aware" backup agent - most decent backup software for Windows Servers should include this. This should be done with Exchange online and should be done *in addition* to any VMWare host or OS level backups you do.

Microsoft have a page about using Windows Server backup [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876854.aspx).

Comment: Do you know which tasks have to be performed before a backup can start? I only have the space for a VM backup, not for additional backups.